# How to group by keys in a list

Tags: scala

I have a list in Scala that I want to group by a key and sum up the values of each key:

```
val l = List(("abc",1),("abc",2),("cbe",5),("cab",1))
```

I tried this code:

```
l.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.sum)
```

But got the following error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[(String, Int),Int]
 required: Seq[(String, Int)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might have been already answered in stackoverflow, but you group and then sum the values of list.

```
scala> val l = List(("abc",1),("abc",2),("cbe",5),("cab",1))
                  .groupBy(_._1)
                  .map { case (k, v) => k -> v.map { _._2}.sum}
l: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = HashMap(cbe -> 5, abc -> 3, cab -> 1)
```

Comment: put everything in one line if you are trying on scala REPL, that way it might be easy. thats directly from my REPL so it must work

Answer (score 2):

***Given List:***

```
val list = List(("abc",1),("abc",2),("cbe",5),("cab",1))
```

***Using,***

```
list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
res13: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(cab -> 1, abc -> 3, cbe -> 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also be done with `groupMapReduce`

```
scala> val l = List(("abc",1),("abc",2),("cbe",5),("cab",1))
                 .groupMapReduce(_._1)(_._2)(_ + _)
val l: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(abc -> 3, cab -> 1, cbe -> 5)
```